# How to select a specific Label depending on where on the UserForm I click?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to programming in VBA, so please bear with me here. I am creating a sudoku program through Excel VBA and I'm creating the game on a UserForm. I'm using Labels as the individual squares on the board and captions to house the individual numbers.

When I click on a Label it defaults all labels back to the original color, then it changes the background color of the Label I clicked and it cycles through all 81 Labels to change any Labels with the same caption to the same background color. This code works without any issues:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ctrlLabel As Control

    For i = 1 To 81
        Set ctrlLabel = Me.Controls("Label" & i)
        ctrlLabel.BackColor = &H8000000F
    Next i

    Label1.BackColor = &HFFFF&

    For i = 1 To 81
        Set ctrlLabel = Me.Controls("Label" & i)
        If ctrlLabel.Caption = Label1.Caption Then
            ctrlLabel.BackColor = Label1.BackColor
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

If I were to use brute-force, this is what each subsequent Label's code would look like:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ctrlLabel As Control

    For i = 1 To 81
        Set ctrlLabel = Me.Controls("Label" & i)
        ctrlLabel.BackColor = &H8000000F
    Next i

    Label2.BackColor = &HFFFF&

    For i = 1 To 81
        Set ctrlLabel = Me.Controls("Label" & i)
        If ctrlLabel.Caption = Label2.Caption Then
            ctrlLabel.BackColor = Label2.BackColor
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

There are only four changes:

`Label2_Click()` (line 1)

`Label2.BackColor` (line 9)

`Label2.Caption` (line 14)

and another `Label2.BackColor` (line 15)

I *could* create 81 Subs and just adjust the code for each one; however, I would like to find an alternate solution, if possible.

I think if I can get the program to select a Label depending on where on the UserForm I click, I can adjust all 81 Labels with one UserForm Sub. I was thinking about using UserForm_Click to trigger code that will search XY position of the click on the UserForm, identify which Label is there, and then adjust that Label accordingly; however, I have been digging through the Excel MSDN and have been unable to find anything that would allow me to do this.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Alternatively, is there a better approach that I am not thinking of?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try searching for "excel userform one event multiple controls".

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is. Are you asking advice on whether you should have 81 controls or 81 sections of the form responding to MouseDown?  Sounds like equal amounts of work. If you go with the controls, don't try to create them manually - code it. Also, have you got the back-end logic finished for this project (ie., on a worksheet)?  It's probably best to first see if you can figure that out before you worry about the UI because the one is likely to affect the other.  Have you checked out some of the 100's of Excel Sudoku games out there to get ideas?